# Gnome animations stopped working. Debian 12

Tags: debian, gnome, graphics, gnome-shell

My Gnome shell animations have completely stopped working. Everything still retains it's functionality, like I can bring my dash to dock up, and moving my mouse to the upper left corner to see the active windows still works, but I want animations on my DE.

I've looked up this issue and some people say to check graphics in about settings, and that correlating to a driver failure (ie. llvmpipe), however, I have `NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3070 Ti Laptop GPU / Software Rendering` in that section, so I assume the graphics drivers are not the root of the problem.

I've tried re-enabling the animations from the command prompt with `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations true`. I've tried to use `sudo startx`, but nothing changes. I'm not sure how to remedy this.

update: I added `deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware` into my sources.list, and tried to reinstall `nvidia-driver firmware-misc-nonfree` however it says I have broken packages.

here is the response:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies: nvidia-driver : Depends: nvidia-driver-libs (= 525.147.05-4~deb12u1) but 525.147.05-4 is to be installed Depends: nvidia-driver-bin (= 525.147.05-4~deb12u1) but 525.147.05-4 is to be installed Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia (= 525.147.05-4~deb12u1) but 525.147.05-4 is to be installed Depends: nvidia-vdpau-driver (= 525.147.05-4~deb12u1) but 525.147.05-4 is to be installed Depends: nvidia-alternative (= 525.147.05-4~deb12u1) but 525.147.05-4 is to be installed Recommends: libnvidia-cfg1 (= 525.147.05-4~deb12u1) but 525.147.05-4 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` 
thank you everyone for your assistance so far.

Comment: please tell us exactly what you've done. We can't guess what "enabling the animations from the command prompt" means to you. Also: you say "it's not the issue". What issue, and how did you determine it's *not* the issue? You need to write your question so that people who have *not* been sitting together with you in front of your computer can follow.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I edited my question a little bit to better explain the issue and solutions I've tried.

Comment: Did you commit any software update ?

Comment: @xMechanica thanks! much clearer now. I think the gsettings method you mention affects only pre-40 GNOME, I think. It's been a while with Gnome. not sure where the manual `startx` comes from, though!

Comment: It clearly says `Software Rendering`. So yeah hardware acceleration is not working, which is needed for animations. You could try to completely remove the NVIDIA driver then reinstalling it.

Comment: I'll try that, @td211 .

Comment: @MC68020 yes, I tried to install the nvidia drivers from the repo of non-free software from debian's wiki. That may have been the root of the problems.

Comment: @that most probably is. Can you revert this update ?

Comment: @MC68020 - I've troubleshooted the package issue, it's still giving me unmet dependencies. I don't know where the package that contains these dependencies may be.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this. It turned out that I accidentally installed sid's nvidia driver package instead of my bookworm driver package. My animations are back.

I added sid's repo back into my `etc/apt/sources.list`, `sudo apt update` and removed `firmware-misc-nonfree`. using `sudo apt remove firmware-misc-nonfree`. I then removed sid's non-free software repository and replaced it with my original bookworm non-free software repo in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

nvidia's driver still brings up unmet dependencies, HOWEVER, my graphics in my about section in settings is updated to `NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3070 Ti Laptop GPU / Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2)` after rebooting. So, I assume it's okay.